# Indent comments in Liferay 6.1

Tags: java, liferay

Googling I've just read that, if I would like to indent comments, I have to set

```
discussion.thread.view=combination
```

but I can't understand exactly ...where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `portal-ext.properties` file. Put this file to the main directory of liferay, also parallel to `tomcat` dir.

Comment: Your solution works, but I haven't indented comments yet! 
I would like to change the view to tree just like as I can do in the forums.
I tried to change combination with tree to display comments as I was looking for.
But it didn't work.
Anyway, the yours is the best answer until now. Thnx!